# Get latest record for each case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with id,ref_id,name,created_on. I'm trying to get  only latest record for each name.
Query that I'm trying :

```
select 
    (case when name = 's1' then created_on end) as serv1,
    (case when name = 's2' then created_on end) as serv2     
from table tsl where id ='6326323'
order by created_on desc
```

Output that i expect

```
serv1                 serv2 
----------------------------------
2020-09-14 07:52:22  2020-09-14 09:12:22
```

output i get

```
serv1                   serv2
----------------------------------------
2020-09-14 07:52:22      2020-10-14 07:52:22
2020-09-13 07:52:22
```

Comment: Seems you need to wrap your `CASE` expressions in a `MAX`.

Comment: If you ever have more than `s1` and `s2` take a look at `ROWOVER`

Comment: `from table tsl where id ='6326323'` This obviously returns two rows. More importantly, it is obvious that the value of 2020-09-14 09:12:22 does not exist in a row with the specified id value where name is S2. If you don't understand your data and your query, it will be difficult to "fix".

Answer (score 1):

Using max helped

```
select 
    max(case when name = 's1' then created_on end) as serv1,
    max(case when name = 's2' then created_on end) as serv2     
from table tsl where id ='6326323'
```

Answer (score 0):

By hardcoding the name you are limiting this to only 's1' and 's2' This will give you the latest records for each name:

```
select * from (
    select *
        row_number() over(partition by name order by created_on desc) as rn
    from
        tsl
    where id ='6326323'
) t
where t.rn = 1
```